# Django detect changes in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I have a model which has a ManyToMany relation with the User model:

```
class ExtraModel(models.Model):
    ...
    extra_relation = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='extra_relation')
```

I want to send an email to users when they are added to this ManyToMany field. We can add them at any time, and this often happens more than once (ie a few users are added at a time).

I've been investigating the best way to do this, and I'm thinking it will be using the `m2m_changed` signal. It seems Django (or at least via the admin panel) first clears alls relations, and then inserts them back in again. Looking at the signals fired, I see 'pre_clear', 'post_clear', 'pre_add' and 'post_add'.

The problem is the 'pk_set' in 'pre_add' and 'post_add' are the same, and 'pre_clear' & 'post_clear' don't have any 'pk_set' attributes. So even if I can work out how to collect the pks at 'pre_clear' (which I don't quite know how to), I'd then have to save them to be compared at the 'post_save' stage (to work out which users have been added.

Is there a good way of doing this? Using signals or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using the m2m_changed signal.

All you need to do is wait for every m2m to be added, passing as sender the through table :

```
m2m_changed.connect(method, sender=ExtraModel.extra_relation.through)
```

Then in your method :

```
method(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    extra_relations = instance.extra_relations.all()
    ...
```

HTH !

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, this is helping me narrow it down a bit. The problem is that when the Django admin panel 'adds' a new relationship, it actually deletes all the keys before adding them all (plus the new one). Thus if I call `instance.extra_relations.all()`, it shows me all relations, not just the new ones. If I look at the 'action' firing signals, I could potentially look at the differences between the keys in the 'pre_clear` and then `post_add` ie before and after the new keys are added. But how do I save the keys from `pre_clear` to then access on the `post_add` signal?

Comment: Oh then I didn't really get what your problem was, sorry. But I don't get why the post and pre add pk_set being the same is an issue ? In both case, it should contain only the pk of the added m2m objects... Are you saying it also contains previous, already saved, objects ?

Comment: Yep. Because the admin module seems to clean the entry by removing all saved objects, and then re-adding them all, the `pk_set` is all objects, including the ones previously there.